# MAUI MVVM - How to populate with data returned from NOSQL into CollectionView

Tags: navigation, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

In my project, our backend is sending student data in form of a JSON object. I've to create a model to inflate that data and a `ViewModel` to make it reactive. I'm using `Communitytoolkit.MVVM`. Data returned from the server looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "6a49c6de7634f86e8cadcae2",
        "firstName": "Suresh",
        "lastName": "Oberoi",
        "photo": "https://nagpur-s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Ss4KAD04Byb4SsmGr5kSOQ4S7XZRhQ.jpeg",
        "graduated": false,
        "coursesTaken": {
            "id": "7a5cc6db90d9e78f630178ae",
            "name": "Intro to DB",
            "semester": "Fall 2020",
            "teacher": {
                "id": "7a5cc6db90d9e78f630178ae",
                "firstName": "Chulbul",
                "lastName": "Pandey",
                "teacherImage": "chulbul.jpeg"
             },
        },
    },
    { /* More documents in same pattern as above */ }
]
```

From this I've to create required models and ViewModels.

I've following questions:

1. Can I create a simple model containing something like so:

   ```
    public class Student {
        public string Id {get, set};
        public string firstName {get, set};
        public string lastName {get, set};
        public string photo {get set);
        public bool graduated {get, set},
        List<Course) coursesTaken {get; set};
    }
   ```

   2. If yes, how can I bind the `Student` model with the viewmodel using `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Your `"coursesTaken"` JSON property is not an array, it's currently a single object. You need to surround the data with `[` and `]` to make it an array of objects. Once fixed, you should be able to deserialize the JSON into your `Student` model. Note that you have typos in your code. Please make sure that the code you show is well-formatted and compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Your class definition doesn't match your Json data. The code `List<Course) coursesTaken {get; set};`  is a list while the json string is an object.

```json
"coursesTaken": {
"id": "7a5cc6db90d9e78f630178ae",
"name": "Intro to DB",
"semester": "Fall 2020",
"teacher": {
    "id": "7a5cc6db90d9e78f630178ae",
    "firstName": "Chulbul",
    "lastName": "Pandey",
    "teacherImage": "chulbul.jpeg"
 }
```

If you want variable `coursesTaken` to be a list, you need to add `[]` outside of the inner json string.

```json
[
  {
    "id": "6a49c6de7634f86e8cadcae2",
    "firstName": "Suresh",
    "lastName": "Oberoi",
    "photo": "https://nagpur-s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Ss4KAD04Byb4SsmGr5kSOQ4S7XZRhQ.jpeg",
    "graduated": false,
    "coursesTaken": [
      {
        "id": "7a5cc6db90d9e78f630178ae",
        "name": "Intro to DB",
        "semester": "Fall 2020",
        "teacher": {
          "id": "7a5cc6db90d9e78f630178ae",
          "firstName": "Chulbul",
          "lastName": "Pandey",
          "teacherImage": "chulbul.jpeg"
        }
      },

      {
        "id": "7a5cc6db90d9e78f630178ae",
        "name": "Intro to DB",
        "semester": "Fall 2020",
        "teacher": {
          "id": "7a5cc6db90d9e78f630178ae",
          "firstName": "Chulbul",
          "lastName": "Pandey",
          "teacherImage": "chulbul.jpeg"
        }
      }
    ]
  }     
]
```

And you also need to check whether the variable `teacher` is a `List` or a normal object. Make sure that the Json data is consistent with the actual defined data type, otherwise the data will not be parsed successfully.

Assuming the Json data is like what I posted above, you can define the code like below:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public string photo { get; set; }

    public bool graduated { get; set; }

    public List<Course> coursesTaken { get; set; } = new List<Course>();

    //public Course coursesTaken { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Course
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string semester { get; set; }

    //public  List<Teacher> teacher { get; set;} = new List<Teacher>();

    public Teacher teacher { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Teacher
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string teacherImage { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(jsonstr);` to convert the json to `List<Student> StudentsList;`

**Note:**

Your code of `Student` is not in the right format.The property should been defined as follows:

```cs
public string yourproperty { get; set; }
```

not

```cs
public string yourproperty {get, set};
```

Comment: It's also conventional to start property names with capital letters in C#.